# I'm making a discord bot that can check google sheets and checks if a date is >= today's date and if so remove a user from a specified role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So im trying to make a discord bot that checks a column of times in google sheets and if that time has exceeded todays date remove the a role from that user.
So i basically grab a row from google sheets and make that equal a varaible called username.
how can i basically do a username.member.roles.remove('15581865116598152');

**MYCODE**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');

    const fs = require('fs');
    const readline = require('readline');
    const {google} = require('googleapis');

    // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
      if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
      // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
      authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
    });

    /**
     * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
     * given callback function.
     * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
     * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
     */
    function authorize(credentials, callback) {
      const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
      const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
          client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

      // Check if we have previously stored a token.
      fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
      });
    }

    /**
     * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
     * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
     * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
     */
    function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
      const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
      });
      console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
      const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
      });
      rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
          if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
          oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
          // Store the token to disk for later program executions
          fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
          });
          callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
      });
    }

    /**
     * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
     * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
     */
    function listMajors(auth) {
      const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
      sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: '',
        range: 'Trials!A2:E',
      }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const rows = res.data.values;
        if (rows.length) {
          console.log('Name, Major:');
          // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
          rows.map((row) => {
            //console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[1]}`);
            console.log(row[0]);     //msg.member.roles.add('699808219400241212');
            var username = row[0];

          });
        } else {
          console.log('No data found.');
        }
      });
    }

})


bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Where are you executing the funtions? in the `message` event?

Comment: What discord.js version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with usernames is not recommended as multiple users can have the same username, so it is recommended to use their IDs instead.

With that said, you need to find the guild member using their username then adding/removing their role.

I am unsure whether you're doing everything in the `ready` or if you're executing the functions in the `message` event, I am also unsure as to what version of discord.js you are using so I'll assume you're using v12. In case you are using v11, just remove all the `.cache`s from the code.

If you are using the `ready` event:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID)
const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.username === username)
member.roles.remove('15581865116598152')
```

If you are using the `message` event however:

```js
const member = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.username === username)
member.roles.remove('15581865116598152')
```

if you are using User IDs instead of usernames, which is recommended:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID)
const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === userid)
member.roles.remove('15581865116598152')
```

Comment: i am getting an error saying (node:23972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined.

Comment: https://discord.com/channels/596416845121191972/675775046693814329
im using the 596416845121191972 as guild id which would be correct
However you said its better to do it by the users ID what would the code look like if i used the ID instead. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: No, that's not how you get a guild ID and I meant using user ID to find members instead of usernames. as for your guild ID issue, enable developer mode then right-click the server and click copy ID: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-

Comment: gnarly that worked . in this google sheets i have everyones userids too and i was able to extract it sucessfully how would i set it up for the userid?

Comment: Check my edit, I just added a way to use user IDs instead of usernames, also accept my answer if it solved your issue and also please delete your other question since it has technically already been answered here

Comment: idk why but now im getting this error, i did delete the other post tho. (node:13276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: var userid = newusername[1];

const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('333014151301562369');

const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.id === userid);

member.roles.remove('706316561996316702');

the userid one, however when i go back to using username it still throw the roles undefined error

Comment: I am using the ROLEID like i should.

Comment: 2 possible causes: **1** the usernames on your sheet do not exist in your guild or they're not **exactly** the same as the ones in the guild. **2** The IDs in your sheet are fetched as `numbers`, do `console.log(userid)` or even `console.log(typeof(userid))` to check if it's a `string` or `number`

Comment: is that the user id after the #? ItIsN3RD#4113

Comment: What? `#` signifies a channel